# asp.net core 6.0 web api unit test using NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to create the simple web api test for the controller action method I have in my project. I already create and add the test project in my solution. And add the Nunit nuget package in test project.

The controller I am trying to test is look like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase

{
   
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private BaseDataAccess _datatAccess = new BaseDataAccess()
   
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
    }

      
    [HttpGet("GetInfo/{code}")]
    public IActionResult GetInfo(string code)
    {
        List<InfoModel> infos = new List<InfoModel>();

        int isNumber;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || !int.TryParse(code, out isNumber))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(String.Format("The code pass as arguments to api is : {0}", code));
            
            return BadRequest("Invalid code");
        }

        try
        {
            
            _logger.LogDebug(1, "The code passed is" + code);
            SqlConnection connection = _datatAccess.GetConnection(_configuration, _hostEnvironment);
            string sql = string.Format ("SELECT * from table1 where code={0}", code);
            DataTable dt = _datatAccess.ExecuteQuery(connection,CommandType.Text, sql);

            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    infos.Add(new InfoModel
                    {
                        ID = dr["id"].ToString(),
                        code = dr["code"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(4, String.Format("Error Message: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace));
            
            return BadRequest("There is something wrong.Please contact the administration.");
        }


        return new OkObjectResult(infos);

    }
}
```

Now when I try to create the unit test I need to pass the configuration, hostenvironment and logger to HomeController from my TestHomeController. And I don't know how to instantiate these settings and pass to controller:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApi.Models;
using MyApi.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace MyApi.Tests
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class TestHomeController: ControllerBase
   {
     private readonly IConfiguration _configuration; //How to instantiate this so it is not null
     private readonly IHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment ;//How to instantiate this so it is not null
     private ILogger<HomeController> _logger;//How to instantiate this so it is not null


    [Test]
    public void GetInfo_ShouldReturnAllInfo()
    {

        var controller = new HomeConteoller(_logger, _configuration, _hostEnvironment);
        var result = controller.GetInfo("11");
        var okObjectResult = (OkObjectResult)result;

        //Assert
        okObjectResult.StatusCode.Equals(200);


    }
}
```

}

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you refer to the point [Creating a Mock Object](https://code-maze.com/unit-testing-controllers-aspnetcore-moq/) in the link. see whether it help you to get an idea regarding setting those objects.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT using the moq object helped to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have startup.cs. Don't you?
if you gonna test a controller, then you need to build a whole instance of an application. Here I put an example of how you can test your code if you have Startup.cs.

```
 public class SUTFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return Program.CreateHostBuilder(null);
    }
}

public class TestControllerTests
{
    private SUTFactory factory;
    private HttpClient _client;
    public TestControllerTests() 
    {
        factory = new SUTFactory();
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task GetPatientInterviewID_ShouldReturnAllInterviewID()
    {
        // Arrange
        var id = "11";

        // Act
        var result = await _client.GetAsync($"Home/GetInfo/{id}");

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

This example is closer to Integration testing rather than Unit-testing. If you want to have unit-test then you need to do the following things

1. BaseDataAccess _datatAccess this is a specific realization and it cannot be mocked (comparing to ILogger, IHostEnvironment etc)
2. move all your code from the controller to a separate class, and test this class.

Comment: maksym  instead of startup.cs my project have Program.cs file.